# Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined - screen flow embedded in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have embedded a screen flow in an Aura component and I want to control the flow's Finish behaviour to redirect to a URL after clicking on Finish.

**Aura component**:

```
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global" >
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}"/>
    </aura:component>
```

**Controller**:

```
({
init : function (component) {
    
// Find the component whose aura:id is “flowData”
var flow = component.find("flowData");
// In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow’s Unique Name.
flow.startFlow("HRCFSL_Create_Work_Order_SF");
},
    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
   if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
      var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
      var outputVar;
      for(var i = 0; i < outputVariables.length; i++) {
         outputVar = outputVariables[i];
         if(outputVar.name === "varWorkOrderId") {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToUrl");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": "com.salesforce.fieldservice://v1/sObject/" + varWorkOrderId.value,
                "isredirect":"true"           
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
         }
      }
   }
}

})
```

When running the flow in the Salesforce Mobile app, I get the error **Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined**. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `e.force:navigateToURL`, not `e.force:navigateToUrl`. Make sure you pay attention carefully in JavaScript, as it is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. If you ever see this, it's because `$A.get` didn't return an object, which is why the variable was undefined/null.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox! That resolved the problem!